# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. (IONIC4)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

Hi friends i have a problem in my code :
its showed the error : (ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.)
i wanted to show the doc from firestore that id i passed it from another page .

my code :
**detail.page.ts**

```
export class DetailsPage implements OnInit {
  id: string;

  news2: any;

  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private afs: AngularFirestore) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(this.id);
   this.news2 = this.afs.collection('123').doc(this.id).snapshotChanges()
.subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
});
}
```

**details.page.html**

```
<ion-content padding *ngFor="let hero of news2">
 {{hero.title}}


</ion-content>
```

Comment: Does `console.log(data)` output the correct array?

Comment: yes its correct

Answer (score 0):

Angular purposefully does not support iteration over object properties with `*ngFor`, because there's no ordering contract like arrays have - which means that the ordering of the list might be inconsistent in the view rendering. I would suggest modifying your **AngularFirestone** API to return an `Array` as news2 instead of an `object`, in order to provide a guaranteed ordering contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

```
<div *ngFor="let pair of obj | keyvalue">
  <p>Object key: {{pair.key}}</p>
  <p>Object value: {{pair.value}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it show :news2 key: _parent

news2 value:

news2 key: _parentSubscription

news2 value:

news2 key: _parents

news2 value:

news2 key: _subscriptions

news2 value: [object Object]

news2 key: closed

news2 value: false

news2 key: destination

news2 value: [object Object]

news2 key: isStopped